# Is there a pattern for one use only objects?

Tags: python, c++, design-patterns

Suppose you are representing some task to do using objects of a class `Task2Do`. These objects are runnable, that is, they have a method which perform a task `doTask`.

On the other hand, you have a queue of these objects (example in python):

```
a = Task2Do(method1, args1)
b = Task2Do(method1, args2)
c = Task2Do(method2, args3)

pending = [a,b,c]
```

You want to run all `pending` tasks:

```
for t in pending:
    t.doTask()
```

It can happen that someone introduces a bug so the same object appears twice in the `pending` queue:

```
pending = [a,a,c]
```

You can protect your code:

```
class Task2Do:
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        self._todo = target
        self._args = args
        self._done = False

    def doTask(self):
        if not self._done: # Protection against double execution
            self._todo(*self._args)
            self._done = True
```

**My question is:** Does this have a name as a design pattern? I heard some people have implemented something similar calling the object destructor in C++.

What other similar patterns do you know?

Comment: Calling an object destructor in C++ sounds like a bad idea to defeat double execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method I can think of is:

```
class Task2Do:
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        self._todo = target
        self._args = args

    def doTask(self):
        self._todo(*self._args)
        self._todo = lambda: None
        self._args = ()
```

which seems cleaner than a flag. Alternatively, make `self._todo` throw an error on second call. You could even do that by just setting `self._todo` to `None`.

---

To be honest, though, tasks don't really need to be classes. Most of the time it's easier and more idiomatic just to have a function. In that case, you could use a generator to get one-time-use:

```
def task2do(target, *args, **kwargs):
    def iter_run_once():
        yield target(*args, **kwargs)
        raise ValueError("Multiple calls to one-time-use task")

    return iter_run_once().__next__

F = task2do(print, 1, 2, 3)

F()
#>>> 1 2 3

F()
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "", line 14, in <module>
#>>>   File "", line 4, in iter_run_once
#>>> ValueError: Multiple calls to one-time-use task
```

For fun, note you can also do:

```
def task2do(target, *args, **kwargs):
    return (lambda: (yield target(*args, **kwargs)))().__next__
```

;)

Comment: +1 Clean and concise! I think a case where the class representation is interesting is that one where the run-it-once atoms are processes (mutiprocessing python library) you may need to represent them using a child class of `Process`. You could instantiate a `Process` within an intermediate `target` however.

Answer (score 1):

A thread pool pattern allows you to push callable objects to a data container and run them on a dedicated set of threads. An advantage of thread pool is that you don't have to launch a thread every time you want to run an object. When the object is run, it is deleted from the container so that it is not run again. If you need additional logic to guard against running objects twice, you can add it to the code where the objects are added to the thread pool or to the code that is run inside the objects.
A good thread pool library is CTPL,  https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl.

Comment: +1 Because your answer provides an elegant solution to the "run each task once" problem, that is, to the specific problem presented in the example. Not accepted because doesn't name or describe a pattern where an object is used once and only once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a design pattern that can help here, but your class Task2Do can be simplified like this:

```
class Task2Do:
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        self._todo = [target]
        self._args = args

    def doTask(self):
        while len(self._todo):
            todo = self._todo.pop(0):
            todo(*self._args)
```

This avoids a `_done` member being accidentally set back to `True` again.